# How to Stop MongDB- Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm testing a site that is on Microsoft Azure, I want to stop the db to check the behaviour of the processes in the site. I can't find an option to do this in Azure.

The db is mongoDB

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You want to actually stop the service? There's no way to do that. You'd need to delete your database.

Comment: Cosmos DB is SASS service hence you can't stop it. Just curious, why do you want to stop it?

Comment: Because I'm trying to test for a connection-failure scenario.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pause or stop a Cosmos DB database. You'd have to delete it.

If you're trying to test for a connection-failure scenario, you could enable the Cosmos DB firewall, and block your own connection.

Comment: Outrageous !! Why would anyone want to work with Cosmos DB or Azure if you can't stop the databases? If you can't test/dev with something without running up the exorbitant costs than forget it.

Comment: @micahhoover - This is probably not the best place for this type of rant. Also, a collection can be scaled down to as little as 400 RU ($25/month). Or, if you're doing dev/test (which seems to be your objective), you can run the emulator, for free, built specifically for dev/test purposes. Or, again for dev/test, you can create a collection, test with it, then delete the collection (and limit your billable to a very short period of time, billed in one-hour increments).